# How to design Flutter textfield Like this

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I want to design the flutter text field like this can anyone help me.

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything?if so- what is not working - show us some code.

Comment: Yes I tried it but not achieve that design.

Comment: You need to show your code in your post  so that other developers can see the issue and help you further

Answer (score 8):

```
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,2,10,2),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
             border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)
          ),
          child: TextField(

            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              labelText: "First Name",
            ),
            controller: controller,
          ),
        )
```

Comment: When I have multiple text field and I am focused only on one text field then how to show active text field border red and rest of the grey.

Comment: you can set a selected textfield when tap and build the widget tree.Then check the select one and set the border based on that. But not sure whether it a correct way of doing.

Answer (score -1):

Use 'labelText' for showing label on top of editfield.